# "Error: Internal error encountered" while running RequestSync to Google Homegraph API - Node.js

Tags: node.js, google-smart-home

I am using a Nodejs client to integrate with Google Smart Home.
When I request to RequestSync API, it sometimes shows the following error.

```
Error: Internal error encountered.
```

Although I saw the above error, it seems that the SYNC request has been triggered properly.
Does anyone know why this happens?
Since the request failed and returned an error, our app retries the RequestSync again and again, so I'd like to fix the error if possible.
Thank you.

#### Environment

- @googleapis/homegraph: 3.0.2
- Nodejs: 18.4.0

Comment: This is usually due to an error that happens when Google Smart Home server sends a SYNC intent for this user but gets error responses. Can you check what is the SYNC response you are returning to Google?

Answer (score 0):

This is usually due to an error that happens when Google Smart Home server sends a SYNC intent for this user but gets error responses. Can you check what is the SYNC response you are returning to Google?

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."